# geom_contour_filled colour palette

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbrewer

I was trying to run the following code, but I can't seem to get to change the colour palette to the Spectral palette from ColorBrewer.  Thoughts?

```
maya <- tibble(
  mass = seq(1, 10, length.out = 10),
  mois = seq(11, 20, length.out = 10)
) %>%
  expand(mass, mois) %>%
  mutate(
    diff = mois - mass * runif(1)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mass,mois,z = diff)) +
    geom_contour_filled() +
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
maya
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any function `colour_fill_distiller`. Do you mean `scale_fill_brewer` or `scale_fill_distiller`? Note that the latter throws an error here due to discrete data.

Comment: I fixed my mistake in the question.  Thank you for spotting that.  That being said, how could I use a colorbrewer palette in the code above?  When I used scale_fill_brewer, it gives me a limited number of colours (the max in the palette), but I want to be able to use it for this graph.  scale_fill_distiller won't work here.  Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand, but I think perhaps `geom_contour_filled` may not be the right tool for the job here. See answer below for a suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, perhaps you're after something like the combination of `geom_raster` with `interpolate = TRUE` and `scale_fill_distiller`?

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  mass = seq(1, 10, length.out = 10),
  mois = seq(11, 20, length.out = 10)
) %>%
  expand(mass, mois) %>%
  mutate(
    diff = mois - mass * runif(1)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mass,mois,fill = diff)) +
  geom_raster(interpolate = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

To expand, `scale_fill_distiller` can interpolate the colour scale to fit a continuous range of values, but it cannot actually interpolate your data, as it were. As far as I know, no such functionality is built into `geom_contour_filled` either. Therefore, I think you either need to do your interpolation by hand before plotting, or rely on something like the interpolation in `geom_raster`.

Comment: Yeah, so this is the route I ended up taking, but I appreciate your explaining why my original method wouldn't work.